# Fiber connection and Media converter

Tags: fiber

I am connecting 2 Ethernet Routers using Single mode fiber cable and Fiber/Ethernet Media converters

- Should i use 1 cord fiber or Duplex Patch Cord between the media converters ? whats the different ?
- how to arrange cords to TX and/or to RX in both ends ??

thank you everyone

Comment: Please quit commenting in answers. Answers are to answer the question, not to comment on other answers. Use the comment feature to comment on the answers.

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can post and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 2):

> Should i use 1 cord fiber or Duplex Patch Cord between the media converters ? whats the different ?

It is likely that your 2nd question answers your 1st question, if you're asking about individual Tx and Rx connections into the converter or your router's optic, it's going to be duplex.  Simplex (1 cord) fibers Transmit (Tx) and Receive (Rx) out of the same cord.

To add a bit more detail.  If you're using single-mode fiber, then that means your router's optic (i.e. SFP) should be at least a "Long Range (LR)" optic.  Whether it is simplex or duplex *also* depends upon what your router's SFP is expecting.  Your router and media converter need to match in this way.

> how to arrange cords to TX and/or to RX in both ends ??

Again, this implies a duplex cable.  The way to arrange Tx and Rx is simple, arrange it so that the link comes up between the routers.  This means you may have to disconnect the fiber, switch Tx and Rx **on one side only** and reconnect it so that the link comes up.

Answer (score 2):

> Should i use 1 cord fiber or Duplex Patch Cord between the media converters ? whats the different ?

That depends on the type of converters/transceivers you're using. For the most common variants 1000BASE-LX or 10GBASE-LR, a duplex fiber pair is required. 1000BASE-BX10 or 10GBASE-"BX"/-BiDi/-BR use only a single strand.

> how to arrange cords to TX and/or to RX in both ends ??

For duplex connectors - SC or LC - the cable should already provide the required crossover: the transmitter on one side needs to connect to the receiver on the other side. If you're not sure or if the single strands are loose, there should be markings on them like A and B, or a white and a yellow ring. Arrange them so that the transceiver sides are crossed. If it's wrong the link won't come up but nothing breaks, just swap them around.

LC duplex connector:
[image: LC duplex connector]

SC duplex connector:
[image: SC duplex connector]

Single-strand transceivers need to be used in complementary pairs, with a 1000BASE-BX10-D on one side and a 1000BASE-BX10-U on the other. Using the exact same type on both sides won't work.